# Keyboard orientation issue in iOS 8.3

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, orientation, uikeyboard, ios8.3

I am facing keyboard orientation problem in iOS 8.3 also my keyboard is goes up when I tried to change the orientation from portrait to landscape.

How can I fix this issue for the time being Apple fix this issue in next release?

[image]